# Import data from excel to Octave

Tags: excel, import, loading, octave

I'm sure you've already done this question several times but hey he runs again, I might say explicitly how can I import data from excel to Octave and once I've made my calculations, the results re-write on the same sheet Octave, it seems to me that I can not do and this and me this concern, they are grateful and have an example of how to do it please show me, really just want to give me an idea of how to perform it, I leave my e-mail in case I want to send greetings code.

Comment: What do you have tried so far ? Post the code.

Answer (score 10):

You can use xlsread/xlswrite from the io package:

```
pkg load io
```

http://octave.sourceforge.net/io/function/xlsread.html

See the examples:

```
A = xlsread ('test4.xls', '2nd_sheet', 'C3:AB40');
```

which returns the numeric contents in range C3:AB40 in worksheet '2nd_sheet' from file test4.xls into numeric array A

Answer (score 0):

My method: To save the Excel data in Simple text format, then copy this text into Word (it remains in column!), then convert "," to ".", finally this column can be copied from Word to Octave worksheet.